# Hardware Specs for Apache/SVN Server With High Transaction Level

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, build-server

I have to ask my company to assemble an svn server with apache. The transaction level is quite high. In fact today I was having problems with it with the current server, and I don't know if the issue is the bandwidth, because the processor never really gets to 100% usage, and RAM does not over-exhausts.

And the apache goes down once a week on average.

The number of users is close to 1000.

What machine specs should I be asking for?

The racks already exist, (I don't know what rack is...) They won't buy another ones. What I need to know is the specs... The base specs are too low for the high transaction I'm currently having, because my apache is falling once a week. (the issue here is that I don't know what to ask for since Nor disk nor ram are my problems). I'm currently asking for 1TB of HD and 16GB of RAM. But since that was not my problem, I do not know if that's enough, and what else I'm forgetting to ask.

Answer (score 1):

**Sorry, but there is no way to answer your question.**

You don't know what the bottleneck is in the current setup, and you have no numbers on current disk I/O or network I/O. And then, Apache crashing might not be a load issue -- it could just be a bug in the software. If that's the case, then adding faster hardware is unlikely to help.

**You should investigate the cause of the crashes first.** For a start, try to enable logging in Apache, and look at what is happening just before the crash.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on linux/unix check the load average with `top` or `uptime`. That will give you a better idea of how taxed your system is.

It sounds to me more like apache is not configured to handle the load. You may want to look in to optimizing that before throwing money at the problem.

Comment: I'm under windows since processes under svn hooks are executables. High amount of transactional concurrency seems to be the problem, but I don't know how to fix it.